# InputTex com 2 ManagedBean

Tags: java, jsf

Bom dia pessoal

Como posso passar o conteúdo de um inputText para 2 ManagedBeans?
Exemplo

```
<p:inputText id=“usuario” value="#{usuarioBeanCelular.usuarioCelular}" />
<p:inputText id=“usuario” value="#{usuarioBeanTelefone.usuarioTelefone}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Não existe essa opção, o value do inputtext só aceita um objeto, conforme consta na documentação: https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_2.pdf. Acredito que vc esteja cometendo um equívoco na modelagem do seu manegedbean, pq precisaria de dois MB para inputar um número de telefone? Não seria mais fácil controlar isso em um mesmo MB? Caso queira continuar com essa opção, uma saída seria vc pegar a instância do segundo MB e passar o valor inputado no primeiro MB.
No primeiro MB vc teria algo assim:

```
Bean bean = (Bean) request.getSession().getAttribute("beanName");
bean.setMeuAtributo(meuAtributo);
```